# How to make a dataframe of windows?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a pandas series:

```
0 x[0]
1 x[1]
...
n x[n]
...
```

and I want to create a [`pandas.Dataframe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) whose rows are the windows of size *k* in the dataframe. So, for *k=2*, we have

```
  1     0
0 x[0]  x[1]
1 x[1]  x[2]
2 x[2]  x[3]
...
n-1 x[n-1] x[n]
```

There are some obvious clunky ways of doing it, but it seems like there should be a one-line way.

Comment: are you looking to `shift` ? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan I am aware of shift, and can obviously do a for-loop where I keep shifting and concatting, but that seems clunky...

Comment: Along the lines of `b = pd.DataFrame({1: a, 0: a.shift(1)})` where `a = pd.Series([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])`? I'm not sure what you mean by the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not ideal, but likely better than a raw for loop would be:

#### Code:

```
def shift_to_columns(vector, k):
    return pd.DataFrame({i: vector.slice_shift(-i)[:len(vector)-k+1]
                         for i in range(k)})
```

#### Test Code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.Series(range(10))
print(data)
print(shift_to_columns(data, 3))
```

#### Results:

```
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
6    6
7    7
8    8
9    9

dtype: int64
   0  1  2
0  0  1  2
1  1  2  3
2  2  3  4
3  3  4  5
4  4  5  6
5  5  6  7
6  6  7  8
7  7  8  9
```

Comment: This IS one line! One could hope for more, as you say, but this is quite good!